# Retroactively altering Google Analytics data

Tags: google, google-analytics

I've just taken over a Google Analytics account that's been going for several years. About a year ago, a filter was applied to show the full domain in page reports (so www.example.com/page/ rather than just /page/).

I know filters cannot be added retroactively, however I was wondering if there's any way I could apply a change to my old data so that it matches the new URL taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using GA360 and have the ability to export your raw data via BQ, then there's no way for your to alter any of your historical data.